# Network Request Crashing only on LTE on iOS 6 using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: crash, asihttprequest, ios6, iphone-5

I'm experiencing a bug on one of my apps with very strange behavior. When initializing a download for several large image files, the app will crash before any download progress occurs. The app is using several `ASIHTTPRequest`'s on an `ASINetworkQueue` with only one concurrent download allowed.

Here are the conditions:

1. iPhone 5 iOS 6.0 AT&T service
2. App was built with iOS 5.1 SDK and is coming from the App Store
3. Crash only occurs over LTE, does not occur on WiFi or '4G'.

Our development team has only been able to replicate this bug on one device. But after it happened once, it happened every single time the request was tried. The app was deleted and reinstalled numerous times, the iPhone was restarted, the iCloud backup was purged, but the crash continued to happen every single time until the device was switched back to WiFi.

```
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-09-26 21:03:14.872 -0500
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x90000010
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34e13f2a objc_release + 10
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34e13490 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 164
2   CoreFoundation                  0x38b5b82c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
3   Foundation                      0x35005d3c __NSThreadPerformPerform + 600
4   CoreFoundation                  0x38bed8f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
5   CoreFoundation                  0x38bed158 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
6   CoreFoundation                  0x38bebf2a __CFRunLoopRun + 642
7   CoreFoundation                  0x38b5f238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
8   CoreFoundation                  0x38b5f0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
9   GraphicsServices                0x30d5b336 GSEventRunModal + 70
10  UIKit                           0x38ce0284 UIApplicationMain + 1116
11  AppName                         0x00003cc6 0x1000 + 11462
12  AppName                         0x00003c54 0x1000 + 11348
```

Any thoughts? I'm thinking it could be a OS bug or something to do with the fact that it was built with the old SDK. The only other similar reports I could find are here: [iOS6 Sunday Ticket App Crashing over 3G or LTE](http://www.dbstalk.com/showthread.php?t=209067).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What may be happening here is a known problem with iPhone 5 on LTE network — when it switches between 4G and LTE, it drops connection for a little while and all your network requests are erroring out.

You may want to disable LTE temporarily (while still having cellular data!) in the settings and try to recreate the problem. Also keep track of how your phone is connected when on cellular network: 4G or LTE.

This is one of the numerous links that you can get google for "iphone 5 at&t lte drops":
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1452242